# How to make a discord.js bot remember numbers given via a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm just making a little inside joke about a sort of "coin" which you "invest in" so I have a very simple command written up till now

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}> has invested €${args} into DKCOIN`);
};

exports.help = {
    name: ["coin", "coin"],
};
```

I want a way where I would be able to save the number (args) in a way that you each time someone "invests" in it the I would be able to have a Total cmnd that gives the total amount of "money" in this coin. Hope this is clear enough for people to understand and possibly help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to look into using a database, for example, MongoDB(https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/register) there are a lot of good tutorials avaliable from a quick google search for how to set it up. With this database you would need to update it every time someone "invests" and you would be able to read from it for the total cmnd!